# Как конвертировать WAVE файл во FLAC?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Суть вопроса такова: есть звуковой файл в `WAVE` формате, он лежит в `NSBundle` и его нужно конвертировать в формат `FLAC`. Каким путем пойти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартными средствами никак, вам нужно собрать libflac для iOS. Конечно, собрать проблематично - поэтому существуют уже собранные. Посмотреть можно [тут](http://wiki.scummvm.org/index.php/Compiling_ScummVM/iPhone).

А дальше смотрите документацию по `flac` или примеры программ.

Comment: За ответ спасибо, но библиотеку libFLAC я уже собрал, пришлось помучать мозг, но оно того стоит.

P.S. кто будет юзать библиотеку из выше приведенной ссылки это возможно тоже пригодится https://github.com/jhurt/wav_to_flac